# Get remote MSMQ object using 'Get-MsmqQueue' in Powershell 4

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-4.0

I am trying to get the MessageQueue object to return in order to add messages to it via Powershell 4.0 cmdlet:

```
Get-MsmqQueue
```

If I am locally on the server with the message queue, I can run the following and an object of type `MessageQueue` is returned:

```
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "myQueueName"
```

Now if I'm on another server where the script needs to live, I can't seem to get the MessageQueue object to return. I've tried plenty of different combinations of single and double quotes, different flags, etc.

```
Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'myServerName.myCompany.com\private$\myQueueName'
Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'myServerName\private$\myQueueName'
Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myServerName.myCompany.com\private$\myQueueName'
Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myServerName\private$\myQueueName'
Get-MsmqQueue -Name "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myServerName\private$\myQueueName"
Get-MsmqQueue -Name 'FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myServerName\private$\myQueueName' -QueueType Private
```

Has anyone had any luck doing this? I'd really appreciate the help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Having the same issue, did you find any workaround?

Comment: @Sebastian I did not. I decided to go another route and use C# instead

Comment: Okay, also using the msmq .Net-Assembly to read from msmq private remote queue. There seems to be a limitation in the get-msmqqueue-cmdlet. But Send-msmqqueue is working for remote queues. Detailed Descrption under https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn391725(v=wps.630).aspx says, that send is the only cmdlet which accepts names of path names, format names, and direct format names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found this to work:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Messaging")
$queuePath = "FormatName:DIRECT=OS:myServerName\private$\myQueueName"
$queue = New-Object System.Messaging.MessageQueue $queuePath

$queue.GetAllMessages()
```